# How to save an array to a file in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am creating a leader board for my game in python and I want it to save it so that I can retrieve it next time I open up the game.

```
Leader_board  = []
Temp_Leader_board = []

PlayerName = str(No1+No2+No3+No4+No5+No6+No7+No8)
Array = [str(Deaths),PlayerName]
Temp_Leader_board.append(Array)
Leader_board = sorted(Temp_Leader_board, key=lambda player: player[0])
```

The last line is to order the score from smallest to largest.

Comment: You have two main options. You could store each element in your list in a custom format. Or you could use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to serialize your list into a file.

Comment: BTW, we call them lists in python, not arrays.

Answer (score 1):

As [@matusko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43501005/1410394) and @Christian Dean stated, what you are looking for is serialization, which Python has a built-in module for called pickle. Personally, since this seems like a simpler serialization usecase, I'd suggest going for cPickle, which does the same thing as pickle but is way faster because it's written in C. [See here](https://pymotw.com/2/pickle/) for a guide on how to use them for serializing different kinds of data.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred solution for simple serialization is `yaml`.  It has the advantage of being human readable, but has the disadvantage of only being able to serialize simple data structures.  It looks like it would work fine in this case:

**Test Code:**

```
leader_board = [
    [30, 'Player A'],
    [10, 'Player B'],
]

import yaml

# save the leader board
with open('LeaderBoard.yml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(yaml.dump(leader_board))

# read the leader board from yaml file
with open('LeaderBoard.yml', 'r') as f:
    read_leader_board = yaml.load(f.read())

# show yaml format and restored data
print(yaml.dump(leader_board))
print(read_leader_board )
```

**Results:**

```
- [30, Player A]
- [10, Player B]

[[30, 'Player A'], [10, 'Player B']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be using a [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for a way to serialize your list so that it can be saved to a file and then read back in later. For serializing python objects, you can use the python module `pickle` ([reference page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)). For info on writing and reading from files, check out [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).